# Mysql replication affected with Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space?

Tags: mysql

I want to know if replication from master to slave is affected/stopped when the slave status shows-Waiting for the slave SQL thread to free enough relay log space.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

The IO thread can't write any more relay log until the SQL thread has processed it so it might be a long running query that is "blocking" replication. You should see it with `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.

More info over at [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slave-io-thread-states.html)

Comment: Thanks for your quick inputs.Yeah, it is shown in the processlist too.How to ensure that replication is not affected because of this?The relay log size limit has been provided due to space issue.

Comment: I was talking about the SQL thread. That should be processing something and be visible in the process list. Once that has finished MySQL should be able to shrink the relay logs and the IO thread should be able to continue.